# How to change this script to zip an array of dirs?

Tags: php, directory, zip, archive

I'm new to SO and new to PHP. I found a script online to zip a directory and I've edited it so that it sends the zip to the browser for download and then deletes the file from the server.

It works fine, however I would like to zip multiple directories instead of just one.

How would I need to alter my script to accomplish this?

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');

$dirToBackup = "content";
$dest = "backups/"; // make sure this directory exists!
$filename = "backup-$date.zip";

$archive = $dest.$filename;


function folderToZip($folder, &$zipFile, $subfolder = null) {
    if ($zipFile == null) {
        // no resource given, exit
        return false;
    }
    // we check if $folder has a slash at its end, if not, we append one
    $folder .= end(str_split($folder)) == "/" ? "" : "/";
    $subfolder .= end(str_split($subfolder)) == "/" ? "" : "/";
    // we start by going through all files in $folder
    $handle = opendir($folder);
    while ($f = readdir($handle)) {
        if ($f != "." && $f != "..") {
            if (is_file($folder . $f)) {
                // if we find a file, store it
                // if we have a subfolder, store it there
                if ($subfolder != null)
                    $zipFile->addFile($folder . $f, $subfolder . $f);
                else
                    $zipFile->addFile($folder . $f);
            } elseif (is_dir($folder . $f)) {
                // if we find a folder, create a folder in the zip 
                $zipFile->addEmptyDir($f);
                // and call the function again
                folderToZip($folder . $f, $zipFile, $f);
            }
        }
    }
}

// create the zip
$z = new ZipArchive();
$z->open($archive, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
folderToZip($dirToBackup, $z);
$z->close();

// download the zip file
$file_name = basename($archive);

header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($archive));

readfile($archive);

// delete the file from the server
unlink($archive);
exit;
```

Thanks for any  help!

Irma

Answer (score 0):

set $dirToBackup to

```
$dirToBackup = array("restricted","ci");
```

and then :

```
foreach($dirToBackup as $d){
    folderToZip($d, $z, $d);
}
```

Thats all.
Regards,

Comment: Thanks so much, this helps a lot. All file and folders are packed into one zip file. 

But say if I zip "folder1" and "folder2", how could I end up with a file structure in the zip like this:

   `zipfile: - folder1 - folder2`

Comment: i corrected the answer by passing the third parameter to the folderToZip function.